# css class inside first class selector

Tags: html, css

I have following html code

```
<div class="span3">

<div class="abc">code for fist div</div>
<div class="abc">code for second div</div>

</div>
```

I need to hide the first division inside span3 division using a external css. Since I have used span3 in other places too, I have to specify the division class as abc when selecting without saying the first child division.

So how can I select the first abc division within span3 ?

Comment: Google about first child selector

Comment: There are many ways you can do it - `:first-child` or `:first-of-type` or `:nth-child(1)` or `:nth-of-type(1)` etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can achieve this by following style

```css
div.span3 div.abc:first-child {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="span3">
  <div class="abc">code for first div</div>
  <div class="abc">code for second div</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Also remember that depending on how you want to hide the element, you have a choice between `visibility: hidden` and `display: none`. Visibility hidden makes it so the element still takes up space on the page, and is similar in some ways to `opacity: 0`. Display none makes it as if the element effectively doesn't exist at all.

Comment: @Asankasanjaya - Good to know that. You can always mark the answer as accepted for future reference.

Comment: I already tried to mark this as the correct one. It says I have to wait for 10 mins